# Regular Expression Attack Vector?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, security

How does one "parameterize" variable input into a Regex in Ruby? For example, I'm doing the following:

```
q = params[:q]
all_values.collect { | col | [col.name] if col.name =~ /(\W|^)#{q}/i }.compact
```

Since it (#{q}) is a variable from an untrusted source (the query string), I have to assume it could be an attack vector. Any best practices here?

Comment: Get it off your server and do it in JavaScript.

Comment: +1 for taking into account that user-supplied regexes can be a form of code-injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Regexp.escape](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001195):

```
>> Regexp.escape('foo\bar\baz$+')
=> "foo\\\\bar\\\\baz\\$\\+"
```

So your code would look something like:

```
q = params[:q]
re = Regexp.escape(q)
all_values.collect { | col | [col.name] if col.name =~ /(\W|^)#{re}/i }.compact
```

Answer (score 2):

So, do you want the user to be able to provide an arbitrary regular expression, or just some literal text that surely can be quoted? If the user can provide both a regular expression and the text it will be attempted matched against, it's not hard to do a DoS-attack by providing an expression with exponential runtime.